Need help for integrating map into the react project
I Want to add the following Map into my React Ts Project. I have tried with React-Leaflet but cannot integrate it. I would really appreciate any help. I'm new with react.
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';


interface WorldMapProps {
  data: { country: string; lat: number; lng: number }[]; // Assuming you pass data with lat/lng and country
}

const WorldMap = () => {
    return (
      <MapContainer center={[50.5, 30.5]} zoom={13} style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100%" }}>
        {/* Add TileLayer for rendering map */}
        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" // You can use other providers like Mapbox if needed
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        />
        <Marker
          position={[50.5, 30.5]}
          eventHandlers={{
            click: () => {
              console.log("marker clicked");
            },
          }}
        >
          <Popup>Marker at this location</Popup>
        </Marker>
      </MapContainer>
    );
  };
  
  export default WorldMap;

I am trying to work with react-leaflet map but it's throwing error for my react version 18.

